# javascript script for automatic labeling of equations inside the tex file

Tags: scripts, javascript

What is wrong with the following code for script of the texstudio

```
var linenumber = 0;
var keynumber = 1;

dialog = UniversalInputDialog(["a","b","c","d","e","g","h","i","j","k"],"Insert The Postfix:","com")
dialog.setWindowTitle("Insert The Postfix")
if (dialog.exec() != ""){
    var postfix = dialog.get("com");
}
while(!cursor.atEnd()) {
    linenumber++;
    line = editor.text(linenumber);
    ind = line.search('\\label{');
    if (ind == -1) {
        continue;
    }
    var env = editor.document().getLastEnvName(linenumber)
    if (env.localeCompare("equation") && env.localeCompare("equation*") && env.localeCompare("eqnarry") && env.localeCompare("gather")) {
        continue;
    }
    cursor.moveTo(linenumber, ind + 6);
    // Serparating key
    var str = line.substring(ind + 6, line.length);
    var ind2 = str.search('}');
    var key = str.substring(0, ind2);
    // Checking what is the key and writing
    if (!key.localeCompare("")) {
        editor.write(keynumber.toString());
        keynumber++;
    } else if (!key.localeCompare("key")) {
        cursor.deleteChar();
        cursor.deleteChar();
        cursor.deleteChar();
        editor.write(keynumber.toString());
        keynumber++;
    }
}
```

This code is intended to label automatically equations with unique labels. Assuming that "\label{key}" is in the tex file. However, when I run texstudio stops. Is there a way to compile it outside the texstudio environment for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will work instead

```
%SCRIPT
dialog = UniversalInputDialog(["","a","b","c","d","e","g","h","i","j","k"],"Insert The Postfix:","com")
dialog.setWindowTitle("Insert The Postfix")
if (dialog.exec() != ""){ 
var postfix = dialog.get("com")
}
cur = editor.document().cursor(1,0,20)
for(i = 1;i<100;i++){
    editor.replace("\\begin{equation}\\label{key}","",cur,"\\begin{equation}\\label{"+i+postfix+"}")
}
```